# Scala: Updating a field of an object in an Option

Tags: scala, scala-option

What is idiomatic way of updating a field in an object inside a scala option?
flag is a boolean field in item,and I just want to reverse its value:

```
val newOption = itemOption.map(item => item.copy(flag = !item.flag))
```

Is this correct way?

Comment: yes. this is correct. Only one correction is that you're not updating anything but creating new instances of `Option` and `Item`

Comment: Probably, you could leverage [Optics](https://github.com/optics-dev/Monocle) if you want something "cleaner" to create a new instance of the internal object. It becomes: `option.map(_.focus(_.flag).modify(!_)) `. [Here](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/ojK3XWHsSiWDnY3aobNofA) the Scastie code. But yes, it is correct!